# Full-text search with permissions using Solr

Tags: c#, security, solr, solrnet

I'm considering using Solr for full-text search. Most of the data that would be indexed would be subject to user permissions (think similar to email inbox search). Can this be accomplished with Solr?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can add one or more attributes (e.g. userid) to the items being indexed in Solr that you can then use as [filter queries](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fq) to limit what a particular user has access to when querying data from the Solr instance

Comment: can you add multiple values of the same attribute? for example, can i add userid 1 and 2 to an item to indicate that both of those users have access to the item?

Comment: Yes, you can use multi valued fields.